# Unable to compile smart contracts

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am learning the tutorials in 「Mastering Ethereum: Building Smart Contracts and DApps」（O'Reilly）

I copied the following [sample code](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/code/truffle/METoken/contracts/METoken.sol) and created a solidity contract(METoken.sol）.

Next, I compiled it with the「truffle compile」 command, but it gave me an error.Please assist, thanks

//Error Message

TypeError: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined

```
// METoken.sol
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol';

contract METoken is StandardToken { 
string public constant name = 'Mastering Ethereum Token'; 
string public constant symbol = 'MET'; uint8 public constant decimals = 2; uint constant 
 _initial_supply = 2100000000;

 function METoken() public {
   totalSupply_ = _initial_supply;
   balances[msg.sender] = _initial_supply;
   emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _initial_supply);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Standard token was renamed to ERC20.sol in openzeppelin contracts 2.0 version.

You have to modify your imports , then the contract will get compile.

Refer..

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/1557

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried rewriting the import statement and OpenZepplin inheritance, but still, it did not work　:_(
 
「import ‘openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol';」
=>「import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';」
  「contract METoken is StandardToken { 」
=>「contract METoken is  ERC20{」

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: It is hard to see in this form, so I put the error message on GitHub.

https://github.com/okahijiki/FaqStackOverflow-/blob/main/truffleCompile.png